# confirm a variable in a Series

Tags: python-2.7

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
data = {'language': ['Java', 'PHP', 'Python', 'R', 'C#'],
        'year': [ 1995 ,  1995 , 1991   ,1993, 2000]}
frame = DataFrame(data)
frame['IDE'] = Series(['Intellij','Notepad','IPython','R studio','VS'])
print frame['IDE']
print 'VS' in frame['IDE']
```

As I show above, 'VS' is one of frame['IDE']. But when I print in the last step, It prints out False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the pandas Series object `frame['IDE']` is looking for your search term in the index. So if you did `print 3 in frame['IDE']` it would be `True`.

Convert the Series to a list and then it will work as expected:

```
print 'VS' in list(frame['IDE'])
```

Or you could do this:

```
print frame.IDE.isin(['VS']).sum() == 1
```

Comment: Thank you! You mean it must convert into a list first ,"VS" can be found in it.
If I want find "VS" in frame, How can I code?
    print "VS" in list(frame) is not correct.

Comment: What do you mean "is not correct"? Does it not print True when you type that line? I think you mean that you don't want to have to convert it to a list, but that doesn't mean it's not correct.

Comment: I added another option in my answer that may be more to your liking ^